# Howto reverse unknown amount of fixed length elements with no delimiting evectively with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, str-replace

I need to match a part of the received data string "the reply" string with a part of the transmitted "request" to a client. A part  of both strings  define the "route" which comprise of the 16 byte mac addresses of 0 or more router macs between the Host/origin mac and endpoint mac in sequence. The routing part of the "reply" string will consist of the reverse of the "request" macs. I need to match the received/reply string's routing info against the "reverse" of the transmitted "request" routing info. It could be that there is no router defined.
The routing information always starts at a fixed location in the string.
               Soo.. REQUEST:FixedlengthHeaderHOSTmacRouter1macRouter2mac..Router(n)macEndpointmac
      REPLY:FixedlengthHeaderEndpointmacRouter(n)mac...Router2macRouter1macHOSTmac

Comment: can you post an example on the inputs and outputs..? I mean what is your expected input.. and what should be your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is "the request" string: *&001E0001AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD0004A302FB0208ED:00,00XXXX!
This is the string elements "to be reversed" "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD" "0004A302FB0208ED"

This is the fixed header: "*&001E0001"

The reply will be : *&001E00010004A302FB0208EDAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD:xxxxXXXX!

I need to check that the reply have "0004A302FB0208ED" and  "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD" in this sequence. The amount of elements can vary but will always be the same amount for "request" and "reply" and will always be the same length ie. 16 chars and only Hex/[0-9A-F] and will always be the same.

Thanx